# String atribuída a uma variável que não está em uma lista

Tags: python-3.x, funções, condição

Neste código abaixo quero que o Python me retorne o sinal de trânsito de 4 semáfaros simultâneos. Como os resultados são aleatórios, as vezes ele me retorna o correto que seria:

Um dos faróis com a luz verde, outro com a luz amarela e os outros dois com a luz vermelha, não necessariamente nessa ordem, porém 1 com a luz verde, 1 com a luz amarela e 2 com a luz vermelha.

Só que umas das saídas que eu me deparei foi: Verde, verde, verde e vermelho.
não consigo identificar o erro. No meu primeiro `if`, se `farol 1` for igual a `verde` minha nova lista agora não contem mais a cor `verde` e não tem nenhuma condição que faça os outros faróis pegar a cor verde.

Postei o código todo, porém meu erro esta somente na função!

```
import random
import _thread 
Lista_De_Carros_Possiveis = ["Ambulância","Polícia","Bombeiros","Passeios"]
Lista_De_Cor_Possiveis = ["Verde","Amarelo","Vermelho"]
Farol1 = ""
Farol2 = ""
Farol3 = ""
Farol4 = ""
Quantidade_De_Carros_Da_Via1 = int(input("Qual a quantidade de carros da via 1 ? "))
 Quantidade_De_Carros_Da_Via2 = int(input("Qual a quantidade de carros da via 2 ? "))
 Quantidade_De_Carros_Da_Via3 = int(input("Qual a quantidade de carros da via 3 ? "))
 Quantidade_De_Carros_Da_Via4 = int(input("Qual a quantidade de carros da via 4 ? "))
 Pegar_Cor_Do_farol = ""
 Via_Carro1 = [""] * Quantidade_De_Carros_Da_Via1
 Via_Carro2 = [""] * Quantidade_De_Carros_Da_Via2
 Via_Carro3 = [""] * Quantidade_De_Carros_Da_Via3
 Via_Carro4 = [""] * Quantidade_De_Carros_Da_Via4
def Cria_Via_De_Carro(Via,L_De_Carros,Quantidade_De_Carros_Da_Via):
for i in range(Quantidade_De_Carros_Da_Via):
    Carro = random.choice(L_De_Carros)
    Via[i] = Carro         


def Cor_Do_Farol (Farol,Lista_De_Cor_Possiveis):    #  Filho
Farol1 = random.choice(Lista_De_Cor_Possiveis) # Pego uma cor do farol
#Farol1 = Pegar_Cor_Do_farol          # faço que farol 1 igual aquela cor
if Farol1 == "Verde" :               # se farol 1 for igual a verde
    Lista_De_Cor_Possiveis_Farol1 = ["Amarelo","Vermelho"]
    Farol2 = random.choice(Lista_De_Cor_Possiveis_Farol1)
    #Farol2 = Pegar_Cor_Do_farol
    if Farol2 == "Amarelo":
        Farol3 = "Vermelho"
        Farol4 = "Vermelho" 
    elif Farol2 == "Vermelho":
        Farol3 = random.choice(Lista_De_Cor_Possiveis_Farol1)
        #Farol3 = Pegar_Cor_Do_farol
        if Farol3 == "Amarelo":
            Farol4 = "Vermelho"
        elif Farol3 == "Vermelho":
            Farol4 = "Amarelo"

elif Farol1 == "Amarelo" :               # se farol 1 for igual a verde
    Lista_De_Cor_Possiveis_Farol1 = ["Verde","Vermelho"]
    Farol2 = random.choice(Lista_De_Cor_Possiveis_Farol1)
    #Farol2 = Pegar_Cor_Do_farol
    if Farol2 == "Verde":
        Farol3 = "Vermelho"
        Farol4 = "Vermelho" 
    elif Farol2 == "Vermelho":
        Farol3 = random.choice(Lista_De_Cor_Possiveis_Farol1)
        #Farol3 = Pegar_Cor_Do_farol
        if Farol3 == "Verde":
            Farol4 = "Vermelho"
        elif Farol3 == "Vermelho":
            Farol4 = "Verde"

elif Farol1 == "Vermelho" :               # se farol 1 for igual a verde
    Lista_De_Cor_Possiveis = ["Verde","Amarelo",]
    Farol2 = random.choice(Lista_De_Cor_Possiveis)
    #Farol2 = Pegar_Cor_Do_farol
    if Farol2 == "Verde":
        Farol3 = random.choice(Lista_De_Cor_Possiveis)
        #Farol3 = Pegar_Cor_Do_farol
        if Farol3 == "Vermelho":
            Farol4 = "Amarelo"
        elif Farol3 == "Amarelo":
            Farol4 = "Vermelho" 
    elif Farol2 == "Amarelo":
        Farol3 = random.choice(Lista_De_Cor_Possiveis)
        #Farol3 = Pegar_Cor_Do_farol
        if Farol3 == "Verde":
            Farol4 = "Vermelho"
        elif Farol3 == "Vermelho":
            farol4 = "Verde"
print("1",Farol1)
print("2",Farol2)
print("3",Farol3)
print("4",Farol4)
```

Comment: Seu código não é "testável" coloque uma chamada à função `cor_do_farol` e o contexto em que ela ocorre para que possamos simular o erro e tentar ajudar

Comment: no final do codigo esqueci de chamar a função. é so chama-lá assim:   Cor_Do_Farol(Farol1,Lista_De_Cor_Possiveis)

Comment: Deu certo? quando vc for testar, pode a saida ser a correta como eu informei no enunciado, porem se tentar mais de uma vez pode aparecer a errada que seria qualquer resultado que seja diferente de um farol pegando verde outro com amarelo e os outros dois com vermelho

Comment: Sera que é pq estou com os 4 farois em uma unica função? no caso cai em mais condições que eu não vejo, ou seja tenho que criar uma função para cada farol?

Comment: Edite o código com a chamada correta pra função

Comment: estou analisando a possibilidade de fazer 4 funções, uma para cada farol, encontrei outro erro, se não conseguir resolver, abro outra pergunta com o novo código e o novo erro. aparentemente 4 funções independentes resolve meu problema.